# npm server fails to start on brand new react native project

Tags: react-native

I just started on a fresh dev environment with Xcode 7.2.1, and installed react-native (0.20.0).  I initialized a test project to see if it would run, and I got the following error:

**~/dev/TestProj/node_modules/react-native/packager ~
packager.sh: line 11: node: command not found**

The iOS Simulator screen says:

**Could not connect to development server.**

**Ensure the following:**
**- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root**
**- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate**

**URL: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true**

Sure enough, if I go into the project folder in a terminal window and run 'npm start' from there, the packager starts and everything works.  In my experience the packager should run by itself though when you run a project with React Native.  Am I doing something wrong here or is there an issue?  Never had this happen with previous versions of RN.

Comment: What are your versions of Node and NPM ?

Comment: node 5.6.0 and npm 3.7.2

Comment: Your error says that node is not installed, or at least not found. The command `node -v` returns v5.6.0 ?

Comment: Yes, it returned that.  I think it's because I moved on to trying to get my old project working, and while trying to use npm to add new packages, I added the following to my .profile.  I'm guessing this fixed it:

    export NPM_DIR="$HOME/.npm"
    [ -s "$NPM_DIR/npm.sh" ] && . "$NPM_DIR/npm.sh"

Answer (score 0):

I moved on to trying to get my old project working, and while trying to use npm to add new packages, I added the following to my ~/.profile. I'm guessing this fixed it:

```
export NPM_DIR="$HOME/.npm" [ -s "$NPM_DIR/npm.sh" ] && . "$NPM_DIR/npm.sh"
```