# React Native packager.sh: line 11: node: command not found

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio-2.3

I initiated a new project with Create-React-Native-App and then ejected from the project. I followed the instructions for the [React-Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#1-install-android-studio) I opened up a virtual device on Android Studio and ran `yarn android` to build the app. I then get this error message:

[image]

I'm currently using Node 8.11.1 and the command is working normally on my terminal. I installed it with NVM.

**In the packager.sh file, this is what line 11 is:**

`node "./local-cli/cli.js" start "$@"`

Here are my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files:

**.bashrc**

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

**.bash_profile**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

source ~/.bashrc

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

In the virtual device, I get the error message: `Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server`

I've found two questions on here related to this problem but one of them was using [Nuclide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535727/react-native-server-packager-packager-sh-line-11-node-command-not-found) and the other guy was using [Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445939/npm-server-fails-to-start-on-brand-new-react-native-project). Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: Did you install `node` correctly? Does `node -v` output anything? How did you install `node`?

Comment: Yes I mentioned in my question that I have node working correctly 8.11.1. I installed it with nvm

Comment: Can you try relaunching that Terminal process by quitting the Terminal? Did you add the `nvm` thing to your `PATH`?

Answer (score 24):

Answer and discussion from: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1448#issuecomment-340757479

The default shell that is opened to run this command doesn't have the NVM node in its PATH. The solution given is to link the existing node install to where the shell expects it to be:

```
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I had to use `sudo` - it failed silently when I left it out (OSX High Sierra)

Answer (score 1):

You can try running below command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/2778527)

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'

Comment: Saved my day <3

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and was using nvm. What I need to do is

```
nvm alias default v8.15.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to update with someone still having this problem.

I tried all above solutions answer above (and some suggestions from github as well), but neither of them worked for my case (I'm using `nvm` and `node` v10.15.3 (TLS))

The final solution I found was to uninstall both `nvm` & `nodejs`, then reinstalled `nodejs` **without** using `nvm` via https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

And it works!